Flask - Return a 17Mb csv file as downloadable response
So, I'm using flask + flask_restx (to have an iterface where internal company users can make requests).
The request will:

allow an input csv file and some extra data in a form
process the csv input file and add extra data
return the file as a response

The problem I have is the response from the swagger interface never arrives.
I've found when I try with a shorter amounts in the response, it will write it in the "response body" section and it's possible to download the csv file from there.
I'm thinking the issue is the response is being shown in the body instead of a direct file download, making swagger to hang up.
Is it possible to return a file as a direct download instead of showing the content in the response body? (I already tried with send_file and send_from_directory with the as_attachment=True attribute without success).
